Creating associated models in Sequelize - Directly or through association?
I'm working on a Node.js application using Sequelize ORM for database management. In my application, I have two models: User and Customer, with a one-to-many relationship, where one user can have multiple customers. Currently, I'm implementing a feature to create a new customer associated with a user, and I'm wondering about the best practice for doing so.
Here's the code snippet I'm currently using:
const { userId } = req.user;
const user = await User.findOne({ where: { userId: userId } });
if (user) {
    await user.createCustomer({
        customerName: customerName,
        customerPhone: customerPhone,
        customerCity: customerCity,
        customerBalance: customerBalance
    });
    return res.status(200).send({ status: true, message: 'customer created' });
} else {
    // Handle case when user is not found
    return res.status(404).send({ status: false, message: 'user not found' });
}


or directly from the Customer Model
const { userId } = req.user;

await Customer.create({customerName: customerName, customerPhone: customerPhone, customerCity: customerCity, customerBalance: customerBalance, userId: userId});


I'm using the createCustomer() method provided by Sequelize to create the customer associated with the user. However, I'm unsure if this is the recommended approach or if I should create the customer directly from the Customer model.
What is the best practice for creating associated models like this in Sequelize? Should I continue creating the customer through the association of the User model as shown in the code snippet, or would it be better to create the customer directly from the Customer model?
